# ¿Cómo alinear a la izquierda la etiqueta hr?

Tags: html5, css

Hola tengo el siguiente código, pero no se como alinear la etiqueta hr a la izquierda, por más que le coloco el text-align no me funciona.

```css
#hr2{ 
   height:5px; 
   width: 30%;
   text-align: left;
 }
```

```html
<hr id="hr2">
```

Comment: `text-align` alinea el contenido (siempre que sea `inline`)  del elemento que lleva la propiedad, no alinea el elemento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es posible de esta forma:

```css
#hr2{ 
   height:5px; 
   width: 30%;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<hr id="hr2">
```

Comment: Gracias me funcionó.

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada si solucionó el problema

Answer (score 2):

Intenta con lo siguiente

```
#hr2{ 
   height:5px; 
   width: 30%;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Comment: Hola no me funciona tampoco con lo que indicas.

Comment: Entonces acomódalo con display: inline-block; Respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Te debió funcionar.

Comment: esta si me funciono:
display: inline-block